# How to prevent the change of original table style after include bootstrap-combined.min.css?

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, datetimepicker

I want to use the awesome bootstrap-datetimepicker like this: [Awesome Example](http://tarruda.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/)

In my html, I have a table with specific style like below:

[image: original table style]

My original html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
table,th,td
{
border:1px solid black;
}
</style>
</head>

<body>

<table>
  <tr>
    <td>Cell A</td>
    <td>Cell B</td>
  </tr>
</table>

</body>
</html>
```

But after I include the bootstrap-combined.min.css, it changed my table style

[image: Table style changed]

Html code after include bootstrap-combined.min.css:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
table,th,td
{
border:1px solid black;
}
</style>
    <link href="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/twitter-bootstrap/2.2.2/css/bootstrap-combined.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen"
     href="http://tarruda.github.com/bootstrap-datetimepicker/assets/css/bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.css">
</head>

<body>

<table>
  <tr>
    <td>Cell A</td>
    <td>Cell B</td>
  </tr>
</table>

</body>
</html>
```

You can try the code here: [try it here](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_td)

**What would be the possible reason to cause the change of the table style and how could I solve this problem?**

Answer (score 1):

[image]Try this

```
table,th,td
{
border:1px solid black;
border-spacing: 1px;
padding:1px;
border-collapse: separate;
}
```

Comment: have you tried your solution before post it as answer?

Answer (score 0):

In bootstrap CSS there is default styling for tables u can overwrite those classes or remove those.

this kind of default styling is in bootstrap css u can remove or overwrite these.

```
table {
    max-width: 100%;
    background-color: @table-bg;
} 
th {
    text-align: left;
}
```